# A finitely generated $k$-algebra which is not a finitely generated $k$-module

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

In Cox's *Ideals, Varieties, and Algorithms*, 
he defined a **$k$-algebra** is a ring which contains the field $k$ as a subring.
Also: A $k$-algebra is **finitely generated** if it contains finitely many elements such that every element can be expressed as a polynomial (with coefficients in $k$) in these finitely many elements.

**Question:** According to this definition, 
$k[x_1, x_2, ..., x_n]$ is a finitely generated $k$-algebra but it is not a finitely generated $k$-module. Am I right? I have this question because being a $k$-algebra is also a $k$-module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you're correct.

The polynomials of the form $x_1^{a_1}\cdots x_n^{a_n}$ form a $k$-basis for $k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$, and there are infinitely many of them.

Comment: do you mean "form a $k$-basis for the module"?

Comment: Well, yes, I am viewing it as a module, but I was calling it "the algebra" to say which module I was talking about. The word "basis" without further context refers to a basis of a module (or vector space). I've edited the answer to clarify.